# Range: mudar cor da barra de progresso no chrome

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, firefox

No *firefox* é possível alterar a cor da barra utilizando: `::-moz-range-progress`. Existe alguma forma de fazer no *chrome* também?

HTML

```
<input type="range" class="bar" min="1" max="100">
```

CSS

```
.bar::-moz-range-progress{
    background-color: rgb(100, 100, 100);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Em Browsers **webkit** vc pode trabalhar com essas classes:

```
::-webkit-appearance: ;
::-webkit-slider-runnable-track ;
::webkit-slider-thumb ;
```

*Aqui tem um artigo de referência* http://brennaobrien.com/blog/2014/05/style-input-type-range-in-every-browser.html (em inglês)

```css
body {
    padding: 30px;
}
input[type=range] {
    /*removes default webkit styles*/
    -webkit-appearance: none;
    
    /*fix for FF unable to apply focus style bug */
    border: 1px solid white;
    
    /*required for proper track sizing in FF*/
    width: 300px;
}
input[type=range]::-webkit-slider-runnable-track {
    width: 300px;
    height: 5px;
    background: #ddd;
    border: none;
    border-radius: 3px;
}
input[type=range]::-webkit-slider-thumb {
    -webkit-appearance: none;
    border: none;
    height: 16px;
    width: 16px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    background: goldenrod;
    margin-top: -4px;
}
input[type=range]:focus {
    outline: none;
}
input[type=range]:focus::-webkit-slider-runnable-track {
    background: #ccc;
}

input[type=range]::-moz-range-track {
    width: 300px;
    height: 5px;
    background: #ddd;
    border: none;
    border-radius: 3px;
}
input[type=range]::-moz-range-thumb {
    border: none;
    height: 16px;
    width: 16px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    background: goldenrod;
}

/*hide the outline behind the border*/
input[type=range]:-moz-focusring{
    outline: 1px solid white;
    outline-offset: -1px;
}

input[type=range]::-ms-track {
    width: 300px;
    height: 5px;
    
    /*remove bg colour from the track, we'll use ms-fill-lower and ms-fill-upper instead */
    background: transparent;
    
    /*leave room for the larger thumb to overflow with a transparent border */
    border-color: transparent;
    border-width: 6px 0;

    /*remove default tick marks*/
    color: transparent;
}
input[type=range]::-ms-fill-lower {
    background: #777;
    border-radius: 10px;
}
input[type=range]::-ms-fill-upper {
    background: #ddd;
    border-radius: 10px;
}
input[type=range]::-ms-thumb {
    border: none;
    height: 16px;
    width: 16px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    background: goldenrod;
}
input[type=range]:focus::-ms-fill-lower {
    background: #888;
}
input[type=range]:focus::-ms-fill-upper {
    background: #ccc;
}
```

```html
<input type="range">
```

**Com CSS e cor na Barra**

```css
input[type=range] {
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  margin: 10px 0;
  width: 100%;
}
input[type=range]:focus {
  outline: none;
}
input[type=range]::-webkit-slider-runnable-track {
  width: 100%;
  height: 12.8px;
  cursor: pointer;
  animate: 0.2s;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 0px #000000, 0px 0px 0px #0d0d0d;
  background: #ac51b5;
  border-radius: 25px;
  border: 0px solid #000101;
}
input[type=range]::-webkit-slider-thumb {
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 0px #000000, 0px 0px 0px #0d0d0d;
  border: 0px solid #000000;
  height: 20px;
  width: 39px;
  border-radius: 7px;
  background: #65001c;
  cursor: pointer;
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  margin-top: -3.6px;
}
input[type=range]:focus::-webkit-slider-runnable-track {
  background: #ac51b5;
}
input[type=range]::-moz-range-track {
  width: 100%;
  height: 12.8px;
  cursor: pointer;
  animate: 0.2s;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 0px #000000, 0px 0px 0px #0d0d0d;
  background: #ac51b5;
  border-radius: 25px;
  border: 0px solid #000101;
}
input[type=range]::-moz-range-thumb {
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 0px #000000, 0px 0px 0px #0d0d0d;
  border: 0px solid #000000;
  height: 20px;
  width: 39px;
  border-radius: 7px;
  background: #65001c;
  cursor: pointer;
}
input[type=range]::-ms-track {
  width: 100%;
  height: 12.8px;
  cursor: pointer;
  animate: 0.2s;
  background: transparent;
  border-color: transparent;
  border-width: 39px 0;
  color: transparent;
}
input[type=range]::-ms-fill-lower {
  background: #ac51b5;
  border: 0px solid #000101;
  border-radius: 50px;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 0px #000000, 0px 0px 0px #0d0d0d;
}
input[type=range]::-ms-fill-upper {
  background: #ac51b5;
  border: 0px solid #000101;
  border-radius: 50px;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 0px #000000, 0px 0px 0px #0d0d0d;
}
input[type=range]::-ms-thumb {
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 0px #000000, 0px 0px 0px #0d0d0d;
  border: 0px solid #000000;
  height: 20px;
  width: 39px;
  border-radius: 7px;
  background: #65001c;
  cursor: pointer;
}
input[type=range]:focus::-ms-fill-lower {
  background: #ac51b5;
}
input[type=range]:focus::-ms-fill-upper {
  background: #ac51b5;
}

body {
  padding: 30px;
}
```

```html
<input type="range">
```

Porém parece que a barra é mais complicado para mudar pelo CSS. Nesse caso tem opção com JS.

http://jsfiddle.net/JnrvG/1/

**E aqui vc pode criar plugins costomizados**

http://danielstern.ca/range.css/?ref=css-tricks#/