# Problemas com a estilização da tag <progress> no CSS

Tags: html, css, html5, css3, progress-bar

Estou com problemas com a estilização de uma tag `<progress>`. Não consigo modificar a cor interna e a parte interna sai meio "quadrada", às vezes até ultrapassando a margem. Como posso resolver?

[image: Imagens das barras de progresso no Chrome e no Firefox]

À esquerda, como ela saiu no Chrome e no Firefox.

Estrutura do HTML:

```
<div class="lateralesquerda">
    <div class="blocosesq habilidades">
        <h5>Habilidades Profissionais</h5>
        <p>qwe123</p> 
        <p> <progress value="60" max="100"></progress></p>
        <p>Lorem Ipsum</p> 
        <p> <progress value="25" max="100"></progress></p>
        <p>abcdef</p>
        <p> <progress value="10" max="100"></progress></p>
        <p>12346</p>
        <p> <progress value="20" max="100"></progress></p>
        <p>zxcv</p>
        <p> <progress value="30" max="100"></progress></p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Estrutura do CSS:

```
@charset "UTF-8";

body{
    font-family: Times, serif;
    text-align: justify;
    background-color: #EBE9E9;
    color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 1);
    /*overflow: hidden;*/
    word-wrap: break-word;
}

p{
    text-align: justify;
    text-indent: 1pt;
}

.lateralesquerda{
    display: block;
    width: 15%;
    border-right: 0.01em solid rgba(193, 193, 193, 0.7);
    float: left;
    background-color: #b0c4de;
    margin-top: -0.47em;
    margin-left:-6pt;
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 10px rgba(193,193,193,0.6);
}

progress{
    display: block;
    width: 15em;
    margin: 1px auto;
    padding: 1px;
    border: 0 none;
    background: #888;
    border-radius: 20px;
}
```

O meu objetivo era fazer algo mais ou menos assim:

[image: Tabela-objetivo]

Desde já agradeço.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sobre a `progress bar` basta vc colocar `overflow:hidden` nela que resolve. Com o `overflow` o `background` vai respeitar o seu `border-radius` .

Outra coisa, em vez de usar `padding` de `1px` para "empurrar" o `progress` para dentro use a propriedade `border` com `1px` :). Dessa forma fica mais fácil para vc controlar o componente.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Veja: *(deixei comentado onde mudei)*

```css
@charset "UTF-8";

body{
    font-family: Times, serif;
    text-align: justify;
    background-color: #EBE9E9;
    color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 1);
    /*overflow: hidden;*/
    word-wrap: break-word;
}

p{
    text-align: justify;
    text-indent: 1pt;
}

.lateralesquerda{
    display: block;
    width: 15%;
    border-right: 0.01em solid rgba(193, 193, 193, 0.7);
    float: left;
    background-color: #b0c4de;
    margin-top: -0.47em;
    margin-left:-6pt;
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 10px rgba(193,193,193,0.6);
}

progress{
    display: block;
    width: 15em;
    margin: 1px auto;
    /* padding: 1px; */
    border: 0 none;
    background: #888;
    border-radius: 20px;
/* coloque overflow aqui */
    overflow: hidden;
    border: 1px solid #888;
}
```

```html
<div class="lateralesquerda">
    <div class="blocosesq habilidades">
        <h5>Habilidades Profissionais</h5>
        <p>qwe123</p> 
        <p> <progress value="100" max="100"></progress></p>
        <p>Lorem Ipsum</p> 
        <p> <progress value="25" max="100"></progress></p>
        <p>abcdef</p>
        <p> <progress value="10" max="100"></progress></p>
        <p>12346</p>
        <p> <progress value="20" max="100"></progress></p>
        <p>zxcv</p>
        <p> <progress value="30" max="100"></progress></p>
    </div>
</div>
```

---

**type="range"**

E sobre esse outro modelo vc vai precisar precisa usar o `<input type="range">`, recomendo que leia aqui: [Range: mudar cor da barra de progresso no chrome](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/265316/range-mudar-cor-da-barra-de-progresso-no-chrome/265324#265324)

Answer (score 1):

Além de colocar `overflow: hidden`, crie um pseudo `::after` para corrigir as bordas.

Ao dar um zoom no navegador, veja como fica mal feita a borda com apenas o `overflow: hidden`:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Veja agora com o `::after` como fica certinho:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

**Teste:**

```css
body{
    font-family: Times, serif;
    text-align: justify;
    background-color: #EBE9E9;
    color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 1);
    /*overflow: hidden;*/
    word-wrap: break-word;
}

p{
    text-align: justify;
    text-indent: 1pt;
}

.lateralesquerda{
    display: block;
    width: 15%;
    border-right: 0.01em solid rgba(193, 193, 193, 0.7);
    float: left;
    background-color: #b0c4de;
    margin-top: -0.47em;
    margin-left:-6pt;
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 10px rgba(193,193,193,0.6);
}

progress{
    display: block;
    width: 15em;
    margin: 1px auto;
    padding: 1px;
    border: 0 none;
    background: #888;
    border-radius: 20px;
    overflow: hidden;
    position: relative;
}

progress::after{
   content: '';
   position: absolute;
   top: 0;
   left: 0;
   width: calc(100% - 2px);
   height: calc(100% - 2px);
   border: 1px solid #888;
   border-radius: 20px;
}
```

```html
<div class="lateralesquerda">
    <div class="blocosesq habilidades">
        <h5>Habilidades Profissionais</h5>
        <p>qwe123</p> 
        <p> <progress value="60" max="100"></progress></p>
        <p>Lorem Ipsum</p> 
        <p> <progress value="100" max="100"></progress></p>
        <p>abcdef</p>
        <p> <progress value="100" max="100"></progress></p>
        <p>12346</p>
        <p> <progress value="20" max="100"></progress></p>
        <p>zxcv</p>
        <p> <progress value="30" max="100"></progress></p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score -4):

```css
progress{
  border: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 15px;
}
progress::-webkit-progress-bar {
  /* style rules */
  background-color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
  border-radius: 20px;
}
progress::-webkit-progress-value {
  /* style rules */
  /* background-color: #3d3d3d; */
  background-image:
       -webkit-linear-gradient(-45deg, 
                               transparent 33%, rgb(0, 153, 255, .45) 33%, 
                               rgb(0, 0, 255, .45) 66%, transparent 66%),
       -webkit-linear-gradient(top, 
                               rgba(255, 255, 255, .25), 
                               rgba(0, 0, 0, .25)),
     -webkit-linear-gradient(left, #000000, #3d3d3d);
  background-size: 35px 20px, 100% 100%, 100% 100%;
  
  border-radius: 20px;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 4px 0.5px rgb(141, 141, 141);
  transition: 10s;
}
```